# Connecting an EXISTING Google App Engine Backend with Android Project

Tags: android, google-app-engine

We are working in a team and I need to connect my GAE to my Android app (I have Api Key and Project Number).

When I click on secondclick -> Google -> Generate App Engine Backend it seems to create a new Backend for me instead copying the instances from the cloud.

How could I do it ?

I'm very new on doing this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried and it worked for me. You can manually add the generated files to your android project. Generate the client lib files(google app engine project) and copy the
xx_appspot_com-java-1.17.0-rc-source to your android project's source folder. Just create another folder inside src folder (android studio)

src
-main
 -java
  -com
   -appspot.xxx.xx(copy xx_appspot_com-java-1.17.0-rc-source and add as library)

src
-main
 -java
  -com
   -xxx.xx(activity.java)

Also, add the generated lib files into the android lib's folder. You can read this tutorial
http://rominirani.com/2014/01/16/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-3/

Answer (score 0):

@Rafa 
You need to connect your GAE project with your android project. You can do this by editing eclipse project settings.

Create a com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.prefs in your project .settings folder and add "connectedProject=". 
Do the same for your android project.

I had the same problem and after some googling I found this page. It solved my problem.

https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/google-cloud-endpoints-for-android/#h.f7irpyw3cics